# It is possible to use Profiler in Android Studio without attaching it to a specific application?

Tags: android, cpu, android-profiler

I am trying to use Profiler in Android Studio to monitor CPU and Memory usage. I want to see how they increase when I start my application. However, I only manage to start it after the application has started because I have to attach it to a session to see anything in the Profiler window.

It is possible to use Profiler in Android Studio without attaching it to a specific application?